# What is the fastest way to determine if an array contains a repeated value?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, time, duplicates

The array can only have a single duplicate or none at all.

I need the algorithm to pass a few unit tests and have different versions that fail different tests.

If you can spot anything wrong with these two solutions or know of any faster ones, I would appreciate it.

Hashing:

This fails the duration tests for an array of size UInt16.MaxValue with and without a duplicate value.

Passed - Empty array does not contain a repeat
 Passed - Small array with no repeats
 Passed - Small array with repeat(Repeated)
 Passed - Small array with repeat(Repeat)
 Passed - Large array with no repeats(Repeated)
 Failed - Large array with no repeats(Duration)
 Passed - Large array with repeat(Repeated)
 Passed - Large array with repeat(Repeat)
 Failed - Large array with repeat(Duration)
 Failed - Combined

```
public bool ContainsRepeat(UInt16[] values, out UInt16 repeat)
        {
            //HASH SET//
            var set = new HashSet<UInt16>();
            repeat = 0;
            foreach (UInt16 value in values)
            {
                if (!set.Add(value))
                {
                    repeat = value;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
         }
```

Sorting and then binary search the duplicate:

This fails the duration test for the same array of size UInt16.MaxValue but only when there are no repeats, but also fails returning the right repeat value when there are, even though it works for a smaller array.

Passed - Empty array does not contain a repeat
 Passed - Small array with no repeats
 Passed - Small array with repeat(Repeated)
 Passed - Small array with repeat(Repeat)
 Passed - Large array with no repeats(Repeated)
 Failed - Large array with no repeats(Duration)
 Passed - Large array with repeat(Repeated)
 Failed - Large array with repeat(Repeat)
 Passed - Large array with repeat(Duration)
 Failed - Combined

```
public bool ContainsRepeat(UInt16[] values, out UInt16 repeat)
        {
            int findRepeatingElement(UInt16[] arr, int low, int high)
            {
                if (low > high)
                    return -1;

                int mid = (low + high) / 2;

                if (arr[mid] != mid + 1)
                {
                    if (mid > 0 && arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1])
                        return mid;

                    return findRepeatingElement(arr, low, mid - 1);
                }

                return findRepeatingElement(arr, mid + 1, high);
            }

            repeat = 0;
            if (values.Length <= 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Array.Sort(values);

            int index = findRepeatingElement(values, 0, values.Length - 1);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                repeat = values[index];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
```

This is my first post so any input about formatting future questions on here is welcome as well :)

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown on these failed tests ?

Comment: no, but the duration needs to be lower than 2 ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new bool array of UInt16.MaxValue elements. Use this array (instead of a HashSet) as a probe to mark a seen value and detect a subsequent duplicate.

```
public bool ContainsRepeat(UInt16[] values, out UInt16 repeat)
{
  var seen = new bool[UInt16.MaxValue]; // O(k) space/time; fixed with very small C
  foreach (UInt16 value in values)      // O(n) time; n <= k, with small C
  {
    if (seen[value]) {
      repeat = value;
      return true;
    }
    seen[value] = true;
  }
  repeat = 0;
  return false;
}
```

This has characteristics of O(n+k) time and O(k) space (k = range), fixed. In this case, k = 2^16 ~ 65k and n <= k as the first-duplicate terminates the search.

While both probe implementations are O(n), this should perform *much* better than using a HashSet due to a smaller constant (C). However, this approach is not advisable on a data-set with UInt32 range values (k = range, where k >> n), for example, as such pays a constant initialization and memory cost.

This characteristic is similar to a [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and the associated space vs. time trade-offs to a general sort.

It might be possible to apply micro-optimizations as well (make sure to benchmark under real-world conditions). Clearing an existing array vs. creating a new array; or using an int and increment+check vs. boolean check+set; or by using unsafe to avoid index range guards.

If that fails in the “large” array case.. good luck towards “fastest”.

Comment: How come, there must be an alternative than creating an array of 4 billion members?

Comment: The specific question is for “fastest” with UInt16 range: the approach is thus equally specialized, just as when a Radix sort is chosen over a general Merge sort.

Comment: So what does that has to do with a huge array ? Please explain that on your answer.

Comment: Updated with clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried this before with a probe array of int but always got out of bounds exceptions, and stupidly, never thought to increase the size beyond the length of the original array